# PHP/XML help google store locator tutorial

Tags: php, mysql, xml

umm basically I'm relatively new to PHP, I've been trying out tutorial (see link below) and I keep on getting an error, I've googled it but nothing seems to work :S

The error I get using Chrome is:
    This page contains the following errors:
    error on line 1 at column 3: xmlParsePI : no target name
    Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

This is the code:

```
<?php
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");

// Get parameters from URL
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = ( isset( $_GET["lat"] ) ? $_GET["lat"] : 37 ); 
$center_lng = ( isset( $_GET["lng"] ) ? $_GET["lng"] : 122 ); 
$radius     = ( isset( $_GET["radius"] ) ? $_GET["radius"] : 25 );

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());

}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

From tutorial the longitude coordinates are negative values

> Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too,"939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View,
>   CA",37.386339,-122.085823

In your code the longitude coordinate of your default is positive.

Change

```
$center_lng = ( isset( $_GET["lng"] ) ? $_GET["lng"] : 122 );
```

To

```
 $center_lng = ( isset( $_GET["lng"] ) ? $_GET["lng"] : -122 );
```

I tested the corrected code and it produces the xml.

Here is my full code

```
<?php
require("dbinfo.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = ( isset( $_GET["lat"] ) ? $_GET["lat"] : 37 ); 
$center_lng = ( isset( $_GET["lng"] ) ? $_GET["lng"] : -122 ); 
$radius     = ( isset( $_GET["radius"] ) ? $_GET["radius"] : 25 );

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());

}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Here is image of result
[image]

Comment: Oh thanks for that! Can't believe I missed that -_- I'm still getting the same error though, I think its something to do with XML because when I remove the line 'header("Content-type: text/xml");' I get no errors but a blank page.

Comment: As I said your code produces valid XML. Is it this code that produces the error?

Comment: ok thanks :D its working now but I can only see the xml when I view the source code, the browser page itself is blank. Any ideas? Sorry for being annoying.

Comment: If `phpsqlsearch_genxml.php`is producing valid XML like my image `phpsqlsearch_map.html` should show Map.